# Correct way of creating list of dictionaries and sorting by value in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Im trying to loop through a query set and create dictionary for every item, and then add every dictionary to a list. I need to check if the dictionary exist and then update the value if it does. My problem is that I don't know how to sort the list by the amount value.

Maybe this is not the best way of creating dicts?

Here is my code:

```
#Create list
my_list_of_dicts = []

#Create dict object
my_dict = {}



#Find every user in query_set
for item in query_set: #query_set is a list of objects from a Django query: <QuerySet [<User: name123>, <User: name123>, <User: name456>, <User: name789>,]>

    if item.name in my_dict:
        #Update object
        my_dict[item.name]['amount'] += item.amount
    else:
        #Create object
        my_dict[itemrecruiter] = {'amount': item.amount, 'not-important' item.foo}


#Add dict to list
recruiters.append(my_dict)


print(my_list_of_dicts)
>>> [{"name123": {"amount": 8, 'not-important': 'foo123'}, "name456": {"amount": 3, 'not-important': 'foo456'}, "name789": {"amount": 20, 'not-important': 'foo789'}}]
```

Comment: In your example you have only one element in the list, is that what you're trying to achieve? or you want list of `{"name123": {"amount": 8,}}`

Comment: Please provide sample query_set. It explains the problem better.

Comment: I might have done something wrong! I want to have a list of every name, and then have the amount associated to the name. Im open to suggestion of making this better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `dict_` is the dictionary variable inside the list (here `a[0]`), you can do this :

```
import operator
output = sorted(dict_.items(), key = lambda x : x[1]['amount'])
```

Output :

```
[('name456', {'amount': 3}), ('name123', {'amount': 8}), ('name789', {'amount': 20})]
```

Comment: Upvoted but why not `output = sorted(dict_.items(), key = lambda x : x[1]['amount'])`

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use add your dictionary to a list when they are holding just one value, you might just complicate your code more. Try this and see if it works for you

```
# Create dictionary here
my_dict = {}

# Query from db
for item in query_set:
    if item.name in my_dict: # If the item already exist in the dictionary 
        my_dict[item.name] += item.amount # just update the amount
    else: # If the item does exit in the dictionary then create it
        my_dict[item.name] = item.amount

>>>print my_dict
{"name123": 8, "name456": 3, "name789": 20}
>>>my_dict["name123"]
8
```

And you can always loop over your dictionary like this

```
>>>>for key in my_dict:
        print key,":", my_dict[key]
name123 : 8
name456 : 3
name789 : 20
```

Comment: Just trying to simplify my question. It holds two values. Amount and another value.